# problem with jquery asp.net webscraping matching mulltiple keywords

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, web-scraping

MY MVC app is supposed to take 2 strings, a URL and a Keyword, when the user hits search, the html code is taken from the URL entered, and it is checked to see how many times the keyword appears, and the results are ordered in a list. The problem is that only 1 result appears as a result.

Here is some of the code (HTML):

```
<input id="urlInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter URL" /> 
<input id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="Enter Keyword" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<div id="twoColumn">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

(3rd div child is the important part)

Jquery:

```
        var userkey = $("#keyword").val();
        keys = html.match(userkey);
        keys = keys != null ? $.uniqueSort(keys) : "";
        var key1 = $("<p><u>Keywords Found:-</u></p>");
        for (var i = 0, il = keys.length; i < il; i++) {
            key1.append("<p>" + (i + 1) + ". " + keys[i] + "</p>");
        }
        $("#twoColumn > div:nth-child(3)").html(key1);
    }
```